# Setup your developer Subscription (MSDN) isn't working

Tags: office365

When attempting to setup our MSDN Office 365 Developer subscription  (adding country, user name, domain, password) and then clicking |Continue| nothing is happening.  Note: Continue button is working as it does spawn message if password verification is incorrect.

Tried with multiple browsers (edge, explorer, firefox, and chrome) as well as on android and using different network connections.

No code, just screen shot...

Hitting continue should create the account.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect SO to do about that issue. We have no input or control over the MS web site. Contact Microsoft directly about issues with their site or services. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions; we're not support for off-site vendors or your account at their site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a third-party vendor site support question and not a programming question.

Comment: Ok… I landed here because it's where the MS support link took me...

Comment: That's for questions related to development. We can't assist with questions related to your specific account or difficulties you're having with registration. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576) for more information.